# Freezing/compiling and piping a java python application?

Tags: java, python, javafx, pyqt, cross-platform

***Background***

I'm making small software for a small company in python, and so far I've made all the backend and frontend side on python. For the ui, I've been using PyQt5, however, I'm having a lot of trouble freezing the ui part of the code in Mac systems, and to be honest, I dont like the looks of the ui on Mac. I've been reading, and seems that JavaFX gives a more native look to desktop applications, in any platform, so I thought on making the frontend side (ui) in java, and backend in python.

***Question***

However, I don't really know how to let the two languages communicate. Is it possible?

And also, how could I freeze or compile both languages on a single '.exe' or '.app'  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly, the answer is yes:

[Combine JavaFX with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43018661/combine-javafx-with-python)

and here is how to turn it into a single executable binary

[creating executable for jython scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022877/creating-executable-for-jython-scripts)

Comment: Thanks a lot!  You solved me thousands of problems. However i think I will migrate the whole code to java, as the backend libraries are purely native.